# C++ program which outputs integers separated by commas

Tags: c++

this program takes in integers and sorts them in ascending order. my problem here is it doesnt output numbers separated by commas, can someone please help me with this?

```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <cstdlib>

   using namespace std; 

   int  main () {    int x;

           int array [10], t;
           for (x=0; x<10; x++)
           {
           cout << "Enter integer number: " << endl; 
           cin >> array[x]; 
           }
           for (x=0; x<10; x++)
           {
                   for (int y=0; y<9; y++)
                   {
                           if(array[y]>array[y+1])
                           {
                   t=array[y];
                   array[y]=array[y+1];
                   array[y+1]=t;
                           }
                   }
           }
           cout << "The integers in ascending order are : ";
           for (x=0;x<10;x++)
           {  
              cout <<"\n";
              cout <<array[x];
              cout << "\n";
           }
        system ("pause");
           return 0;  
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just print commas instead of new lines

```
for (x=0;x<10;x++)
       {  
          cout <<array[x]<<",";
       }
```

Comment: cout << "The integers in ascending order are : ";
        for (x=0;x<10;x++)
        {  
         
           cout <<array[x];
           cout << ",";
        }

Comment: i made these changes to it and it worked, thank you :)

Comment: glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Correct the last for group as follows:

```
for (x=0;x<10;x++)
{  
    cout <<array[x];
    cout << ",";       
}
```

Comment: cout << "The integers in ascending order are : ";
        for (x=0;x<10;x++)
        {  
         
           cout <<array[x];
           cout << ",";
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
 cout << "The integers in ascending order are : ";
        for (x=0;x<10;x++)
         {  

           cout <<array[x];
           cout << ",";  ---> changed this line and it prints output with commas
    }
```

thank you everyone for helping me, i appreciate it :)